# Generator function not executed PHP

Tags: php, generator, fgets, yield

In the following code, I don't get 'handled' on my output. I see the filehandle a resource, the file gets opened en the contructor of FqReader is called, I checked all that. But with execution of FqReader::getread() I don't see output and the returned array is empty. The first while loop also does not get exectuted when I put while(1) instead of the logic test as in the code now.

```
<?php

class FastqFile {
    function __construct($filename) {
        if (substr($filename, -3, 3) == '.gz') {
            $this->handle = gzopen($filename, 'r');
            return $this->handle;
        }
        else
            $this->handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
            return $this->handle;
    }
}

class FqReader {
    function __construct($file_handle) {
        $this->handle = $file_handle;
    }
    function getread() {
        while ($header = fgets($this->handle) !== false) {
            echo "handled";
            $bases = fgets($this->handle);
            $plus = fgets($this->handle);
            $scores = fgets($this->handle);
            yield array($header, $plus, $scores);
        }
    }
}

$filename = $argv[1];
$file_handle = new FastqFile($filename);
var_dump($file_handle);
$reader = new FqReader($file_handle);
var_dump($reader->getread());
```

It outputs:

```
object(FastqFile)#1 (1) {
  ["handle"]=>
  resource(5) of type (stream)
}
object(Generator)#3 (0) {
}
```

Comment: When I loop through like foreach ($reader->getread()) echo $read[0] I get a warning: PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/niels/Projects/umi/fastqgz.php on line 21 but it says it's a resource of type (stream) right? So I'm baffeled

Comment: `$this->handle` is not a resource, it is an object of type `FastqFile`

Comment: As an aside, returning anything from a constructor doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file_handle` is a `FastqFile`instance. Then you pass that object to `fgets()`, but you need to pass that object's handle to `fgets()`. For instance:

```
class FqReader {
    function __construct($file_handle) {
        $this->handle = $file_handle->handle;
    }
    function getread() {
        while ($header = fgets($this->handle) !== false) {
            echo "handled";
            $bases = fgets($this->handle);
            $plus = fgets($this->handle);
            $scores = fgets($this->handle);
            yield array($header, $plus, $scores);
        }
    }
}
```

The usage of `yield` was not showing you that error.

Comment: Also it's useless to return something in a `__construct`

Comment: Why is that? Better to use just a function instead here, right?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, this works like a charm:

(using a function to open file, not a class)

```
function openfq($filename)
{
    if (substr($filename, -3, 3) == '.gz') {
        $handle = gzopen($filename, 'r');
        return $handle;
    }
    else
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
        return $handle;
}

class FqReader {
    function __construct($file_handle) {
        $this->handle = $file_handle;
    }
    function getread() {
        while (($header = fgets($this->handle)) !== false) {
            echo "handled";
            $bases = fgets($this->handle);
            $plus = fgets($this->handle);
            $scores = fgets($this->handle);
            yield array($header, $bases, $scores);
        }
    }
}

$filename = $argv[1];
$file_handle = openfq($filename);
var_dump($file_handle);
$reader = new FqReader($file_handle);
var_dump($reader->getread());
foreach($reader->getread() as $read) {
    var_dump($read);
}
```